# Is WCF good backend for Flash Games?

Tags: wcf, flash

Let's say Im building an online Poker similar to Zynga's Poker Game.
Is wcf a good backend for that?

Comment: If it's easy to communicate over IP with Flash, then I guess WCF could do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, you might be best off going with what you know. Since you mentioned WCF, I'm assuming you have some .NET background and it would be easier for you to develop in .NET than learn a new language and framework. If that's the case, several options present themselves:

1. Go with WCF, since it's the de facto standard in the Microsoft world for building services. Recognize that, with WCF, you have the option of going with a SOAP-based service or a lighter weight RESTful service using WCF WebHttp. As one of the other posters mentioned, you're probably better off going with WebHttp to avoid the overhead of SOAP.
2. Look at an option like Adobe's [FluorineFx](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) which will allow you to program in .NET and gain the benefits of advanced Adobe remoting technologies and protocols (such as the AMF binary protocol) that are otherwise only available on the Java platform.

Practically speaking, I've seen both WCF SOAP and WCF WebHttp services integrate with Flex-based clients nicely. I've never seen Fluorine used in practice with most clients that want to leverage the AMF protocol choosing to go the Java route.

Answer (score 0):

gaming means high traffic and wcf is not lightweight. I recommend simple REST pages implemented on asp.net mvc 3. A more better and simple solution is (if you know java) developing rest pages on playframework with japid module. The best way in my opinion is (if you know scala) implementing it on playframework with scala module. Play with both japid and scala modules is much more performant, light and simple than asp.net mvc 3.

my best,

Serdar Irmak